# Forcusrite Scarlett 8i6 in Ubuntu 14.04!

Tags: sound, usb-drive, audio-recording

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 but I can not make my Focusrite Scarlett 8i6 card work in the system.

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Now I am very grateful!

Comment: what is a "Focusrite Scarlett 8i6", what have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, I think I did not explain myself properly!

Scarlett 8i6 is an external audio interface manufactured by Focusritte!

I installed the software it through Wine along with PlayOnLinux! It opens but states that the hardware is not connected.

I realized that some software such as Ardour, recognize it as a USB connection, not even her name appearing in the program's preferences.
However, it does not appear in the system options such as "Audio Driver" to be chosen. Audio of the internet still comes out of laptop cases and not the output of Scarlett as it should occur.